# How to save previous URL on Password Reset Blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a blade with a password reset code (e.g. edit.blade)

I want to make that after a successful password change the user can return to the page from which he went to this blade (by pressing "Exit").

But the standard solution:

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}"> Exit </a>
```

doesn't work because after successfully updating the password and displaying a message about it, the previous URL becomes URL that belongs to edit.blade.

How can I save the route from which the user entered the edit.blade??

Comment: I would look into session flashing, using reflash to keep the data until you're ready to recover it.  laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#flash-data

Comment: try `return back()`

Comment: `return Redirect::intended();` might be what you look for.